# Blocking read from FIFO via ifstream object

Tags: c++, file-io, filestream, fifo

I open a FIFO file as `ifstream`. As soon as the object is created the thread is blocked until I send something into the FIFO (which is OK for me). Then I call `getline()` to get the data from the stream.

How do I read-block the thread again until more data is written into FIFO file?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this code but I'm wondering if the FIFO is simply setting the EOF bit when you read all available data.  In that case, you might be able to do this:

```
std::ifstream fifo;
std::string   line;
bool          done = false;

/* code to open your FIFO */

while (!done)
{
    while (std::getline(fifo, line))
    {
        /* do stuff with line */
    }
    if (fifo.eof())
    {
        fifo.clear();  // Clear the EOF bit to enable further reading
    }
    else
    {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

If you read off the end of the FIFO, reset and wait for further data.  If an error occurred, you're done.  I got the idea for this from [this website](http://www.usenet-forums.com/linux-general/89222-named-pipes-c.html).  You might have to also close and reopen the FIFO in the same block where you do the reset.

Comment: Is this busy waiting? When we reset the EOF bit what stops EOF being reset and us spinning?

Comment: Don't you mean `fifo.clear()`? `std::ifstream` does not seem to have a `reset()` method. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/clear

Comment: No down vote but that code never stops, as already mentioned (busy waiting). I just want to emphasis again on that.

Answer (score 1):

The `getline` function provided by `<string>` returns a reference to the stream object.  You can test this object for "goodness" to see if it's still open or if an error has occurred:

```
std::ifstream fifo;
std::string   line;

/* code to open your FIFO */

while (std::getline(fifo, line))
{
    /* do stuff with line */
}
```

When the FIFO closes, the while test will return false to exit the loop.  Every loop iteration will effectively read-block the thread until more data is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I use the stream as follows:

```
ifstream _FifoInStream(_FifoInFileName.c_str(), ifstream::in);

string CmdLine;

while (std::getline(_FifoInStream, CmdLine)) {
    cout << CmdLine << endl;
}
```

I'm blocked only when I initialize _FifoInStream variable i.e. open the stream. After I send data into FIFO I fall through the while block. What I need is to read from FIFO indefinitely each time being blocked on read.

Comment: Do you close FIFO after sending data? E.g., if  you use echo command to send data, echo opens FIFO, sends data and then closes it.

Comment: I do. Echo is exactly what I use.